# Woo-Commerce Variable Products on sale Sorting not working

Tags: wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I am trying to sort the products on "order by sale". This works fine on simple products but it doesn't sorts the variable products by sale price and ignores them. I also tried the "WooCommerce Extra Product Sorting Options" Plugin and it is also not applying sorting on variable products. Is there any other way to sort both Simple and Variable Products with same order.
Thanks

Comment: Yes "WooCommerce Extra Product Sorting Options" not working for both Simple and Variable products on shop page. Working only for simple products

Comment: @TajdarKhanAfridi what wrong with you I already told you what needs to be done. :) :)